# web3 reading memory string gives error

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs

i have declared a string variable in struct like

```
struct test{   
     string  testString;
  }
```

I have written a function to access the variable like

```
 function getteststring(uint256 index)public returns (string memory)
      {           
              return test[index].testString;            
      }
```

when i try to call this function using web3.js i get "0xc05205ee00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001" , converting this to UTF8 fails Error: Invalid continuation byte

can anyone guide me on how to access  this var and convert in readable format

Answer (score 1):

`test` is a `struct` not an `array`. You simply can't write something like `test[index]`.

If you want make an array of struct below code might help.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.4;

contract A{
    struct test{
        string  testString;
    }
    test[] tests;

    constructor() public {
        tests.push(test("aaa"));
        tests.push(test("bbb"));
        tests.push(test("ccc"));
    }

    function getteststring(uint256 index)public view returns (string memory){
        return tests[index].testString;        
    }
}
```